# Using XCUIElementQuery to query a button in tableHeaderView not found

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, uiaccessibility

I want to using Xcode UI Test to help me automation testing my app.

My view hierarchy like: UITableView->TableHeaderView->My custom view->Setting button.

I want to query my button with accessibilityIdentifier, I set it in my viewController, and check it with Simulator's accessibility inspector, and using my real device with voice over check the button is accessibility.

But with my code, it can't be founded:

`app.tables.buttons["settingBtn"].tap()`

Why my setting button is accessibility but Xcode can't record it and the code by myself can't found the setting button?

Can someone give me some tips to using the UIElementQuery with right way to access my button?

--- Edit ---

In custom view:

```
@implementation HeaderView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self initAccessibility];
}

- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return NO;
}

- (NSArray *)accessibilityElements {
    return @[self.settingButton];
}

- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount {
    return [[self accessibilityElements] count];
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element {
    return [[self accessibilityElements] indexOfObject:element];
}

- (void)initAccessibility {
    self.settingButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.settingButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"settingBtn";
    self.settingButton.accessibilityLabel = @"settingBtn";
}

- (IBAction)clickSettingButton:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(clickSettingButton)]) {
        [self.delegate clickSettingButton];
    }
}

@end
```

in viewController:

```
- (void)initHeaderView {
    self.headerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([HeaderView class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    self.headerView.delegate = self;
    [self.headerView.backgroundImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kURLString]];
    [self.headerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREENWIDTH, (SCREENWIDTH * 9 / 16))];
    self.headerViewHeight = self.headerView.bounds.size.height;
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.headerView];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.headerViewHeight, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.headerViewHeight + kNavigationBarHeight);
}
```

in UI test code:

```
class PopupDialogUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        continueAfterFailure = false
        XCUIApplication().launch()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }    

    func testExample() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()

        app.tables.buttons["SettingBtn"].tap()
    }

}
```

Comment: That query looks correct. Can you post more of your application code to help debug?

Comment: Can you post the output of `app.tables.buttons.debugDescription`?

Comment: @Oletha , the debugDescription is:  Find: Descendants matching type Table
    Output: {
      Table 0x7fb6505e84e0: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
    }
    ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Button

No button found in the table, but in accessibility inspector, it's look like this: http://imgur.com/uUEOVaQ

Comment: @JoeMasilotti, the application code just like the edit, if need more information, please tell me, thanks!

Comment: What's the output when you click the button with the record tool?

Comment: @Oletha:http://imgur.com/FZW0ADF

Comment: Does removing the `tables` part of the query help at all?

Comment: @JoeMasilotti, no, it's still can't query it

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's been over a month since you asked this question, but I noticed you still didn't have a solution to your issue. You are using an uppercase 'S' at the beginning of your string when specifying the accessibility identifier in your test, when it should be lowercase.

```
- (void)initAccessibility {
    self.settingButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.settingButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"settingBtn";
    self.settingButton.accessibilityLabel = @"settingBtn";
}

app.tables.buttons["SettingBtn"].tap()
```